# How to create a you-Tube like video player using Brightcript for Roku?

Tags: youtube, video-player, roku, brightscript

I am a newbie in ROKU development. I  got my hands on it couple of days ago. I want to create a **video player for my Roku device with look and feel of Youtube**. I want my video player to launch in small window mode and show the list of videos on the right side just like Youtube does. Moreover I also want to add a **button to maximize and minimize the screen**.

I have researched on it. I have tried video Player example that comes with Brighscript sdk. I have also tried to work with few custom video player examples available online but did not help to achieve exactly what I want.
**How can I add Buttons on a video player in bright script and How do I make that button to minimise and maximise the window in bright script.can anyone provide me  code for that??**

I have downlaoded the custom video player  that uses rovideoplayer.
Here is the Main.brs code:

```
Sub RunUserInterface()
    o = Setup()
    o.setup()
    o.paint()
    o.eventloop()
End Sub

Sub Setup() As Object
    this = {
        port:      CreateObject("roMessagePort")
        progress:  0 'buffering progress
        position:  0 'playback position (in seconds)
        paused:    false 'is the video currently paused?
        feedData:  invalid
        playing:   0
        playingPrev: 0
        playlistSize: 0
        canvas:    CreateObject("roImageCanvas") 'user interface
        player:    CreateObject("roVideoPlayer")
        load:      LoadFeed
        setup:     SetupFullscreenCanvas
        paint:     PaintFullscreenCanvas
        create_playlist_text: CreatePlaylistText
        drawtext:  false
        eventloop: EventLoop
    }
 this.targetRect ={x: 350, y: 100, w: 600, h:500}
  '  this.targetRect = this.canvas.GetCanvasRect()
    this.textRect = {x: 520, y: 480, w: 300, h:200} 

    this.load()
    'Setup image canvas:
    this.canvas.SetMessagePort(this.port)
    this.canvas.SetLayer(0, { Color: "#000000" })
    this.canvas.Show()

    this.player.SetMessagePort(this.port)
    this.player.SetLoop(true)
    this.player.SetPositionNotificationPeriod(1)
    this.player.SetDestinationRect(this.targetRect)

    this.player.Play()
    this.playingPrev = this.playing

    return this
End Sub

Sub EventLoop()
    while true
        msg = wait(0, m.port)
        if msg <> invalid
            if msg.isStatusMessage() and msg.GetMessage() = "startup progress"
                m.paused = false
                print "Raw progress: " + stri(msg.GetIndex())
                progress% = msg.GetIndex() / 10
                if m.progress <> progress%
                    m.progress = progress%
                    m.paint()
                end if

            'Playback progress (in seconds):
            else if msg.isPlaybackPosition()
                m.position = msg.GetIndex()
                print "Playback position: " + stri(m.position)

            else if msg.isRemoteKeyPressed()
                index = msg.GetIndex()
                print "Remote button pressed: " + index.tostr()
                if index = 4  '<LEFT>
                    m.playing = m.playing - 1
                    if (m.playing < 0)
                        m.playing = 2
                    endif
                    m.player.SetNext(m.playing)
                    m.player.Play()
                    m.playingPrev = m.playing
                else if index = 8 '<REV>
                    m.position = m.position - 60
                    m.player.Seek(m.position * 1000)                
                else if index = 5 '<RIGHT>
                    m.playing = m.playing + 1
                    if (m.playing > 2)
                        m.playing = 0
                    endif
                    m.player.SetNext(m.playing)                    
                    m.player.Play()
                    m.playingPrev = m.playing                    
                else if index = 9 '<REV>
                    m.position = m.position + 60
                    m.player.Seek(m.position * 1000)
                else if index = 2 '<Up>
                    if m.drawtext
                        m.playing = m.playing - 1
                        if (m.playing < 0)
                            m.playing = m.playlistSize-1
                        endif
                        m.paint()
                    endif                
                else if index = 3 '<Down>
                    if m.drawtext
                        m.playing = m.playing + 1
                        if (m.playing > m.playlistSize-1)
                            m.playing = 0
                        endif
                        m.paint()
                    endif                
                else if index = 13  '<PAUSE/PLAY>
                    if m.paused m.player.Resume() else m.player.Pause()
                else if index = 6 'OK
                    if m.drawtext
                       m.drawtext = false                   
                       if m.playing <> m.playingPrev
                            m.player.SetNext(m.playing)                     
                          m.player.Play()
                          m.playingPrev = m.playing
                       endif
                    else
                        m.drawtext = true
                    endif
                    m.paint()
                end if

            else if msg.isPaused()
                m.paused = true
                m.paint()

            else if msg.isResumed()
                m.paused = false
                m.paint()

            end if
        endif
    end while
End Sub

Sub SetupFullscreenCanvas()
    m.canvas.AllowUpdates(false)
    m.paint()
    m.canvas.AllowUpdates(true)
End Sub

Sub PaintFullscreenCanvas()
    splash = []
    list = []

    if m.progress < 100
        progress_bar = {TargetRect: {x: 350, y: 500, w: 598, h: 37}, url: "pkg:/images/progress_bar.png"}
        color = "#00a0a0a0"
        splash.Push({
            url: "pkg:/images/splash.png"
            TargetRect: m.targetRect
        })
        list.Push({
            Text: "Loading..."
            TextAttrs: { font: "large", color: "#707070" }
            TargetRect: m.textRect
        })        
        if m.progress >= 0 AND m.progress < 20
            progress_bar.url = "pkg:/images/progress_bar_1.png"
            print progress_bar.url
        else if m.progress >= 20 AND m.progress < 40
            progress_bar.url = "pkg:/images/progress_bar_2.png"
            print progress_bar.url
        else if m.progress >= 40 AND m.progress < 75
            progress_bar.url = "pkg:/images/progress_bar_3.png"
            print progress_bar.url
        else
            progress_bar.url = "pkg:/images/progress_bar_4.png"
            print progress_bar.url            
        endif
        list.Push(progress_bar)

    end if

    if m.drawtext
       textArr = m.create_playlist_text()
       yTxt = 100
        color = "#00000000"
        index = 0
        for each str in textArr
            if index = m.playing
              textColor = "#00ff00"
            else
              textColor = "#dddddd"
            endif
            list.Push({
                Text: str
                TextAttrs: {color: textColor, font: "medium"}
                TargetRect: {x:200, y:yTxt, w: 500, h: 100}
            })
            yTxt = yTxt + 100
            index = index + 1
        end for
    else
        color = "#00000000"
        list.Push({
            Text: ""
            TextAttrs: {font: "medium"}
            TargetRect: {x:100, y:600, w: 300, h: 100}
        })
    endif

    'Clear previous contents
    m.canvas.ClearLayer(0)
    m.canvas.ClearLayer(1)
    m.canvas.ClearLayer(2)    
    m.canvas.SetLayer(0, { Color: color, CompositionMode: "Source" })
    if (splash.Count() > 0)
        m.canvas.SetLayer(1, splash)
        m.canvas.SetLayer(2, list)
    else
        m.canvas.SetLayer(1, list)
    endif
    list.Clear()
    splash.Clear()
End Sub

Function LoadFeed() as void
    jsonAsString = ReadAsciiFile("pkg:/json/feed.json")
    m.feedData = ParseJSON(jsonAsString)
    m.playlistSize = m.feedData.Videos.Count()
    contentList = []
    for each video in m.feedData.Videos
        contentList.Push({
            Stream: { url: video.url }
            StreamFormat: "mp4"
        })
    end for    
    m.player.SetContentList(contentList)    
End Function

Function CreatePlaylistText() as object
    textArr = []
    for each video in m.feedData.Videos
        textArr.Push(video.title)
    end for
    return textArr
End Function
```

Any suggestions regarding the approach I should follow or some thing that point me in the right direction and could give me a good head start would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use roScreen with roVideoPlayer. But It is needs lot of efforts to get the completely custom design with roScreen.

Comment: can you hsow me any example how can I add buttons to my video screens and if possible code on those button click events to mimimise and maximise the screen??

Comment: How can I add facebook share button to my channel??

Comment: you can answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872607/how-to-add-a-facebook-share-button-to-a-private-roku-channel